# Inequality with $\int \ln x dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm trying to prove that for all $k \ge 2$, $$\frac{1}{2}(\ln(k)+\ln(k-1)) \le \int_{k-1}^k \ln x dx$$ without directly solving the integral. I looked at some options, including checking to see whether $\ln x$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}(\ln(k-1)+\ln(k))$ on $x \in [k-1,k]$, but that isn't true. I do know a general definition of convexity ($f(tx-t(1-y)) \le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y),$ $t \in [0,1]$, $x,y \in I$ if $f$ is convex on $I$), but I don't think this will help. Any starting points I should consider?

Comment: Draw a picture, and ln is concave

Comment: What will that have to do with the integral on the RHS?

Comment: The integral is the area under the curve (compare that to the area under the trapezoid on the left side of the inequality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left side of your inequality is the area of a trapezoid

with vertices $(k-1,0), (k,0), (k,\ln k),$ and $(k-1, \ln(k-1))$.

The right side of the inequality is the area under the curve for $\ln x$ from $x=k-1$ to $x=k$.

Since $\ln x$ is concave, the area under the curve is greater than the area of the trapezoid.

It would help to draw a picture.